# GPU stats with AMDGPU Pro driver?

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics

How can I check the GPU/Memory load and other stats? I have Ubuntu 16.04 with an RX 480 with AMDGPU Pro drivers.

I've only been able to check the gpu temperature via `sensors` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Radeon Top](https://github.com/clbr/radeontop) did the trick for me in the end.

Although you do have to compile it.

Bonus advice:

When compiling this edit the Makefile and change `amdgpu ?= 0` to `amdgpu ?= 1`. This will activate monitoring of RAM usage as well as the temperature.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: installation has been streamlined with: `sudo apt-get install radeontop`. see article here: https://awesomedetect.com/how-to-monitor-amd-ati-or-radeon-gpu-usage-in-linux/

Comment: On compiling the latest source on my 20.04.3 (5.11.0-37-generic) i'm getting `FATAL ERROR: xcb/dri2.h: no such file or directory` EDIT - install by `sudo apt install libxcb-dri2.0-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I only know [GLXOSD](https://glxosd.nickguletskii.com). This is pretty much like MSI afterburner OSD for linux, but only works on OpenGL though.